# Nested fetch/then methods

Tags: reactjs, fetch, flickr

I am using the flickr API to search images and I would like to get photos with theirs tags at same time.

To do it, I need first to use *flickr.photos.search* method to fetch the photo_id and build the photo url (1st and 2nd 'then' methods). In the 3th 'then' part I used another API method *flickr.photos.getInfo* to get the tags for each photo and finally return urlPhoto and tagsInfo like json.

The problem is that tagsInfo variable continues been a promise and I can not render the tags (array) of the photo. However, urlPhoto has a correct value.

```
export function fetchAll(...) {
    return fetch(BASE_URL + encodeGetParams(params1), options)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.photos.photo.map(e => 
        ({
          "photo_id": e.id,
          "urlPhoto": 'https://farm'+e.farm+'.staticflickr.com/'+e.server+'/'+e.id+'_'+e.secret+'.jpg',
        })
      )
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.map(e => {
        const url = BASE_URL + encodeGetParams({ ...params2, "photo_id": e.photo_id });
        const tagsInfo = fetch(url, options)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => data.photo.tags.tag.map(e => e._content));

        return {
          "urlPhoto": e.urlPhoto,
          "tagsInfo": tagsInfo       
        }
      }
      )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate promise for each element in the array, use `Promise.all` on those promises and return that.

```
export function fetchAll(/* ... */) {
  return fetch(BASE_URL + encodeGetParams(params1), options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const promises = data.photos.photo.map(e => {
        const result = {
          urlPhoto: `https://farm${e.farm}.staticflickr.com/${e.server}/${e.id}_${e.secret}.jpg`
        };
        const url = BASE_URL + encodeGetParams({ ...params2, photo_id: e.photo_id });

        return fetch(url, options)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            result.tagsInfo = data.photo.tags.tag.map(e => e._content);

            return result;
          });
      });

      return Promise.all(promises);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but (sometimes). Sometimes the error of CORS header is not present returns. I declared in the beginning of the function options={ method: 'GET', mode: 'cors'} and I am using the same for both fetch calls (inner and outer). I am not sure why sometimes not work it.

Comment: @PavelAngelMendozaVillafane You're welcome! That you get cors issues sometimes sounds odd. Not sure what that could mean. When you get the error, are there no CORS headers present in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Do you not just need to return the last fetch and add an extra `.then` that would resolve to

```
{
  "urlPhoto": e.urlPhoto,
  "tagsInfo": tagsInfo       
}
```

like

```
export function fetchAll(...) {
    return fetch(BASE_URL + encodeGetParams(params1), options)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.photos.photo.map(e => 
        ({
          "photo_id": e.id,
          "urlPhoto": 'https://farm'+e.farm+'.staticflickr.com/'+e.server+'/'+e.id+'_'+e.secret+'.jpg',
        })
      )
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.map(e => {
        const url = BASE_URL + encodeGetParams({ ...params2, "photo_id": e.photo_id });
        return fetch(url, options)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => data.photo.tags.tag.map(e => e._content))
        .then(tagInfo => {
          return {
            "urlPhoto": e.urlPhoto
            "tagsInfo": tagsInfo       
          }
        })
      }
      )
    })
}
```

What you're currently doing is returning the urlPhoto/tagsInfo before the tagsInfo fetch promise has resolved so an extra then should fix it!